# put the individual list name to the last column in the list?

Tags: r

I would like to add the individual list name to the last column, respectively. what is the best way to do that efficiently.

```
lst <- list(a=matrix(runif(10), nrow=5, ncol=2), b=matrix(runif(6), nrow=3, ncol=2))

$a
      [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.5257330 0.52673079
[2,] 0.2103107 0.23357179
[3,] 0.3745236 0.03687697
[4,] 0.9731074 0.15569480
[5,] 0.2248541 0.60258915

$b
      [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.9901820 0.3648310
[2,] 0.8922225 0.4285105
[3,] 0.6963518 0.5795353
```

I would like this one: it means the individual list name should be added in the last column, respectively.

```
$a
     [,1]                [,2]                 [,3]
[1,] "0.52573303761892"  "0.526730791199952"  "a" 
[2,] "0.210310699883848" "0.233571790158749"  "a" 
[3,] "0.374523550504819" "0.0368769748602062" "a" 
[4,] "0.973107369150966" "0.155694802291691"  "a" 
[5,] "0.224854125175625" "0.602589153219014"  "a" 

 $b
      [,1]                [,2]                [,3]
[1,] "0.990182007197291" "0.36483103595674"  "b" 
[2,] "0.892222490161657" "0.42851050500758"  "b" 
[3,] "0.696351842954755" "0.579535307129845" "b"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Kevin

Comment: `lapply(names(lst), function(x) cbind(lst[[x]], x))`? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks Ananda. My question is like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233358/element-as-the-list-names-and-list-name-as-the-element-in-a-list   My method is very poor, but may work after using your answer as the medium step. So I look for a better method, that is why I ask your question. @Rcoster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that keeps the names from the original list:

```
mapply(function(x, y) cbind(x, y), lst, names(lst))
```

Comment: Funny that sample code that doesn't work (`names(a)` should be `names(lst)`, I suppose) gets upvoted while an answer that *does* work doesn't get any. Hmm. I'll never understand voting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I forgot to change my test variable to example's variable... And he is new here, give a chance to him!

Comment: Thanks you guys understand, and I have modified names(a) to names(lst) when I tested the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that gives you exactly what you asked for. Based on your expected output, it seems like you're aware that by doing so, you're coercing the numbers in the matrix to characters.

```
lapply(names(lst), function(x) {
  `colnames<-`(cbind(lst[[x]], x), NULL)
} )
# [[1]]
#      [,1]                [,2]                [,3]
# [1,] "0.497699242085218" "0.934705231105909" "a" 
# [2,] "0.717618508264422" "0.212142521282658" "a" 
# [3,] "0.991906094830483" "0.651673766085878" "a" 
# [4,] "0.380035179434344" "0.125555095961317" "a" 
# [5,] "0.777445221319795" "0.267220668727532" "a" 
# 
# [[2]]
#     [,1]                 [,2]                [,3]
# [1,] "0.386114092543721"  "0.86969084572047"  "b" 
# [2,] "0.0133903331588954" "0.34034899668768"  "b" 
# [3,] "0.382387957070023"  "0.482080115471035" "b"
```